# Setting ContentLength on HttpWebRequest gives me a timeout error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an android app that connects to my website's api using C# and xamarin. After debugging for a while I realised that when I set the ContentLength the apps seams to hang and then throws an TIMEOUT exception.

I have tried to not set the ContentLength but then the body seams to not send with the request.

```
public void Post(object data, string route){

    string JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    var web = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://httpbin.org/post");
    //web.ContentLenfth = JSON.length;
    web.ContentType = "application/json";
    web.Method = "POST";

    try{
        var sw = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
         sw.Write(JSON);

        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        var sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If ContentLengt is set the app hangs until the timeout function is called
else the test-url I am posting to tells me that I did not send a body

What do I have to do in order to send a successful `POST` request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the length to be the length of the byte array you are sending (not the length of the string)

You can get the byte array from the json string by doing:

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JSON);
```

Then you can set the content length:

```
web.ContentLength = bytes.length;
```

And send the bytes:

```
using (var requestStream = web.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Ahh Thank you ! I have literaly been trying everything I could find for a couple of hours now !